# Granting RBAC access to specific resource groups in Azure in a specific subscription

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

I have a situation where where `userA` who has reader role assigned to the resource group called `rg_report_prod`. `rg_report_prod` is within the subscription called `sub_production`.

The problem now is that `userA` needs access to only the resources in the resource group rg_report_prod, the user complained that they cannot access the resource group using the subscription pane in Azure, the user was granted reader role rights at the subscription level, now they can see all resource groups which is not ideal.

Is there a way to restrict the user to just the resource group called `rg_report_prod` and nothing else.

After doing some research and reading a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554682/azure-resource-group-access) , a user suggested granting access to the subscription without assigning a role at the subscription level, this is not possible. When assigning permissions at the subscription level, a role needs to be selected.

Any possible solutions here ?

Comment: To restrict the user to specific resource group, you need to assign role to that user under that **resource group** scope only. You cannot add user to subscription without assigning any role. To access the resources, user need to search for that **resource group** name and click it instead of accessing them via subscription pane in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to restrict the user to just the resource group called
> `rg_report_prod` and nothing else.

To restrict the user to specific resource group, you need to assign ***Reader*** role to user under that **resource group** scope only like this:

[image]

To access the resources, user has to enter the **resource group** name directly in search bar and click on it, rather than accessing them through the subscription pane in Azure.

[image]

Now, user should be able to access and manage resources **only within** the **`rg_report_prod`** resource group without having visibility into other resource groups in that subscription.

[image]

**Reference:**
[Understand scope for Azure RBAC | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/scope-overview)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, from a usability perspective I am guessing the user needs to know the name of the resource group. this could be a problem in cases where there are a lot of resource groups, is there a middle ground here where users do not need to memorise/remember the resource group name ?

Comment: Could you check and confirm whether the user can access the resource group from *Resource groups* pane like this https://i.imgur.com/kOYPMel.png and https://i.imgur.com/bgfoRG0.png without need of entering resource group name?